# Simple Moving Average, but ignoring zeroes

Tags: moving-average, pine-script

How do I calculate simple moving average, but ignoring zeroes.
For example, I have a series of values e.g. 5.95, 2.5, 0, 0, 6.5, 0, 2.4, 0, 1.9 and so on. All values are positive (greater than zero). In this case, the average that I am looking for is (5.95+2.5+6.5+2.4+1.9)/5 = 3.85
I have 8 difference variables in a script. I am trying to calculate a moving average for them.

On a side note, while googling for this problem, I came across filters and transforms. Is there any such mathematical concept that can be applied to my problem.

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have tried so far? Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why don't you just take usual `sma` from official doc https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_sma and skip there zero values? And then divide sum of non-zero values by amount of non-zero values?

Comment: Don't post the same question in multiple forums to avoid getting different people helping you simultaneously, as is happening here. Michel, an answer was already given in Pine Script chat on TV.